# Reg-ex explanation for outcome

Tags: html, css, regex, required

```
wiki_page = urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/superman')
html_code = wiki_page.read()
headline  = findall ('<h1.*><span.*>(.+)</span></h1>', html_code)
```

So i want an explanation as to why this example code spits out the word "Superman" and not everything from the start of the findall query through to the end:

for example this is the code of the find all, below and it auto outputs the result:

```
<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" lang="en">
    <span dir="auto">
        Superman
    </span>
</h1>
```

Comment: edit my @msrd0 is incorrect.There should not be space or newline characters as per your regex

Answer (score 1):

Because `re.findall` function tries to spits out the characters inside the capturing groups first. If no capturing groups present then only it spits out the matched strings.

Remove the capturing group from your regex inorder to display the matched strings.

```
<h1.*><span.*>.+?</span></h1>
```